# Parameterizations of negative binomial densities (dnbinom) in R

Tags: c, r, statistics

I'm hoping this belongs here rather than a math forum.

I'm trying to calculate in R the density of a negative binomial. My parameters are currently in the form of `mu` (the mean number of failures expected) and the overdispersion parameter `k`. Since I'm calling `dnbinom` in compiled C code, I need to convert these parameters to the default parameterization of `dnbinom`, which expects the probability of success per trial `p` and the number of successes `n` before counting stops. I used the following equations to solve for `p` and `n` in terms of `mu` and `k`:

```
n = mu*p/(1-p)
mu + mu^2/k = n(1-p)/p^2
```

After a bit of algebra, I get

```
p = k/mu + 1
n = -(mu^2+k*mu)/k
```

Checking these equations with the different parameterizations of `dnbinom` in R reveals a problem:

```
> k = 1.2
> mu = 15
> p = k/mu+1
> n = -(mu*k+mu^2)/k
> dnbinom(10,size=n,prob=p)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In dnbinom(x, size, prob, log) : NaNs produced
> dnbinom(10,mu=mu,size=k)
[1] 0.03560668
```

What about R's parameterization am I missing? I'm pretty sure by now that my algebra's correct. Alternatively, is there a way to stick with the original parameterization (in terms of `mu`and `k`) when calling `dnbinom` from C?

Comment: I do not know how you got `n = -(mu^2+k*mu)/k` as above this formula you wrote `n = mu*p/(1-p)` which looks fine.

Comment: Apologies. It's

    p = k/(k+mu)

which means `n` = `k`, as it should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `?dnbinom` says: size "**Must be strictly positive**, need not be integer"

In your example

```
 n = -(mu*k+mu^2)/k
 n
 [1] -202.5
```

So `dnbinom` fails.

I think n should be `mu*p/(1-p)` after calculating `p` (as you wrote also above), so in this way:

```
k = 1.2
mu = 15
p = k/(k+mu)
n = mu*p/(1-p)
dnbinom(10,size=n,prob=p)
    [1] 0.03560668
dnbinom(10,mu=mu,size=k)
    [1] 0.03560668
```

What looks fine.

Comment: I'm sorry--I tried to quickly note the mistake in my algebra in an answer, but I just saw my answer was deleted... for not being a valid solution (?!). I didn't realize I needed to spell it out. My error was in deriving `p`: `p=k/(k+mu)` and thus `n`=`k`. As you write, the numbers are then consistent.